# Android Google calendar All Day Event start time and end time issue

Tags: android, time, calendar

I am reading the calendar events using CalendarContract api , code works fine except for all day events.

Eg : Log statements

1. Event title  ...All day event test
2. Event start time LOCAL ...2014-03-21 05:30:00
3. Event start time GMT ...2014-03-21 00:00:00 +0000
4. Event end time GMT ...2014-03-22 00:00:00 +0000
5. location  ...Same Day Loans UK
6. organizer  ...sabcexample@gmail.com
7. notes  ...The information contained within this time

Are every "All Day Event" suppose to start at 00:00:00 GMT and end at 00:00:00 GMT same day with 0 duration?

In iphone it returns start time as 00:00:00 GMT till 23:59:00 of same day.

One idea I could think of is manipulating the time explicitly.
But What could be workaround for this issue ?or am I missing something ?